# No puedo insertar archivos de mi google Drive en mi web

Tags: google-drive, cloud, drive

Tengo archivos de imagen y vídeo almacenados en Google Drive que los insertaba en mi web a través de este código:

[https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={File ID}](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Owp_Ll4Wxpbpo1CKpmN-xwVLtGKCcTpz)

Pero desde hace unos días no funciona

Comment: No somos soporte de Google, esta pregunta deberías hacerla a Google.primero, no?. En todo caso, revisa las políticas de uso de Google, tal vez algo haya cambiado sin que te enterases.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿qué significa "no funciona"? ¿Has revisado la consola del navegador para ver si hay errores? ¿Has revisado la pestaña de "red" del navegador para ver si hay problemas durante la llamada a los vínculos de tu Google Drive?

Comment: desde hace unos días me sucede lo mismo. consulté a soporte de google y no respondieron. gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Hay un problema reciente [ya reportado en Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319531488). Lo que no podemos saber es si estamos ante un bug o si Google ha decidido bloquear este tipo de acceso a las imágenes alojadas en Drive. Al parecer están ocurriendo cambios con respecto a las cookies de terceros, siempre según un comentario en Issue Tracker que enlaza a [esta página de blog de Google](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/10/upcoming-changes-to-third-party-cookies-in-google-drive.html).

Como bien te señala @MauricioContreras en su comentario, esto es un azar y si en un futuro Google decide cambiar la URL o bloquear del todo el acceso a las imágenes te puedes quedar pillado. Una mejor forma de trabajar este tipo de cosas es mediante alguna API.

Revisa el hilo de Issue Tracker, donde se aportan soluciones momentáneas al problema, como usar el patrón:

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id={IDIMAGEN}&sz=w{TAMAÑO}
```

Por ejemplo:

```html
<img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=14c67W8sWwKRJShrj14ab3uu6fatSYx6g&sz=w150">
```

Supongo que en el seguimiento de ese hilo se sabrá también si finalmente es un bug o si se trata de un cambio arbitrario de Google.

Como recomendación final, guarda el patrón que vayas a usar en una constante con marcadores, así, si el patrón cambia, solamente tendrías que cambiar esa constante y no recorrer cientos o miles de archivos para cambiar ese dato o, en el peor de los casos, empezar a adivinar en qué archivos de tus miles estás usando ese tipo de código para luego reemplazarlo.